# Hibernate one to one mapping with composed key doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have one-to-one hibernate mapping between class Report and class Flyleaf.
The listed code is successfully executed and the mapping works good.

In my real model the primary key of a report is composed of an "id" and an "index" and so does flyleaf (because its primary key is the primary key of a report).

How can I change my code in order to make the primary key composite (I tried, but an exception was thrown when I want to get list of reports and I also tried to define the key as a PKClass).
(I'm using Hibernate and Spring if this can help)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="report_t")
public class Report {

    private int id, nbPage;
    private Flyleaf flyleaf;

    public Report() {}

    public Report(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="nb_page")
    public int getNbPage() {
        return nbPage;
    }

    public void setNbPage(int nbPage) {
        this.nbPage = nbPage;
    }

    @OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "report", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Flyleaf getFlyleaf() {
        return flyleaf;
    }

    public void setFlyleaf(Flyleaf flyleaf) {
        this.flyleaf = flyleaf;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID : "+id+"\t nb page : "+nbPage+"\n\t"+flyleaf;
    }   
}

    @Entity
@Table(name="flyleaf_t")
public class Flyleaf {

    private int id;
    private String title, author, checker;
    private Report report;

    public Flyleaf() {}

    public Flyleaf(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",
            parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "report_t"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column (name="title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Column (name="author")
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    @Column (name="checker")
    public String getChecker() {
        return checker;
    }

    public void setChecker(String checker) {
        this.checker = checker;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Report getReport() {
        return report;
    }

    public void setReport(Report report) {
        this.report = report;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Flyleaf [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", author="
                + author + ", checker=" + checker + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Please adhere to the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Did you mean the name of classes which countain "_"? because variables and methods (geters and setters) are compliant with the Java naming conventions.@LewBloch

Comment: You tell me. What in your code does not adhere to the Java naming conventions?

Comment: I really don't know what does not adhere to the Java naming conventions. If you hint to the fact that the two classes are public, they are in two separated files. @LewBloch

Comment: Google for "Java naming conventions". Underscores conventionally are only used in constant variable names.

Comment: I usually use underscore just for constant variables. I copyed my classes and add _t to distinguish them. But this is not the source of the Hibernate one-to-one exçeption. Thank you @LewBloch